# Нужно ли здесь тире после выражения "в некоторых случаях"?

Tags: пунктуация

Если же речь идет об индустриальном применении, тяжелых режимах эксплуатации и агрессивных транспортируемых средах, то выбор существенно сокращается, в некоторых случаях до 10–20 производителей.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемые вариант

(1) Если же речь идет об индустриальном применении, тяжелых режимах эксплуатации и агрессивных транспортируемых средах, то выбор существенно сокращается (в некоторых случаях до 10–20 производителей).

(2) Если же речь идет об индустриальном применении, тяжелых режимах эксплуатации и агрессивных транспортируемых средах, то выбор  сокращается существенно,  до 10–20 производителей в некоторых случаях.

Пояснение

Вариант1.   Добавочное сообщение  оформлено в виде вставки. Присоединительная конструкция с тире в конце СПП смотрится и читается хуже.

Вариант2. Обособление обстоятельства со значением пояснения (насколько существенно).

Answer (score 0):

Тире необходимо. См. [Академический справочник.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108)

Comment: Нет, я имела в виду, конечно, не 10-20 производителей, а тире после "в некоторых случаях": Если же речь идет об индустриальном применении, тяжелых режимах эксплуатации и агрессивных транспортируемых средах, то выбор существенно сокращается, в некоторых случаях — до 10–20 производителей. Но, мне кажется, оно здесь лишнее.

Comment: Вы правы: тире здесь лишнее. Исправьте, пожалуйста, тогда заголовок. Я думал, вы имели в виду количество, поэтому исправил заголовок.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тире поставил. Только **не после, а до**  "в некоторых случаях":

*Если же речь идет об индустриальном применении, тяжелых режимах эксплуатации и агрессивных транспортируемых средах, то выбор существенно сокращается -- в некоторых случаях до 10–20 производителей.*